# Possible to rollback changes to MySQL databases without any form of backup

Tags: mysql, database-restore

I understand I might be asking the impossible but, well never hurts to try.

Is it possible to rollback changes to a handful of MySQL databases without having any form of backup. The only thing left are the databases with the changes I wish to undone.

Why this happened you might ask, well simply putting it, Windows XP scheduler decided not to run the backup task as scheduled, therefore no backups were made previous to a few dozen queries queried to those databases.

I doubt it is possible to undo those changes, and if it is possible I don't know how.
Maybe MySQL keeps some sort of record on the changes performed to a database, but I don't know.

Does anybody knows a way to undo changes to a MySql database without any form of backup 
(neither dump file or files from the data folder)?

Thank you.

> **System Details:**
>
> Windows XP SP3
>
> Server: localhost via TCP/IP
>
> Software: MySQL
>
> Software version: 5.5.25a - MySQL Community Server (GPL)
>
> Protocol version: 10
>
> Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

---

**Update**

Possible that Windows XP system restore kept a previous version of
MySQL DBs on file?

Comment: Do you have any full-disk backups? You might be able to recover old versions of the underlying mysql data files.

Comment: @octern: No, there was no need to backup a entire disk once the system only handles with MySQL. Simpler and lighter to backup the databases, unfortunately Windows task scheduler left me to dry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without having any database backup, you are probably pretty much out of luck.  If you had mysql query logging or binary logging on, you could glean some information about what queries had been run since a certain point in time, but if you had destructive queries (UPDATE, DELETE, etc.) you will have no way of knowing what the previous data was.

Comment: Yes you're right, some of the queries were destructive so no luck there. Check my update and say what you think about it, thanks.

Comment: You update doesn't really help.  Even if you had some Windows-level system backup, if it wasn't taking a backup of the MySQL database correctly (i.e. with tables locked and all transactions flushed to disc) there is not guarantee that your physical MySQL data files are not corrupted, or that they represent some exact point in time state.  In fact, in the case of just some system-level backup, they are probably just the state of the tables at different points in time (i.e. times when backups started on each table file).

Comment: Do you know were I can find those backup files from Windows, if they exist. I could give a shot a see if it worked.

Comment: @FábioAntunes I would imagine that would store backups according to whatever your settings are.  I don't use Windows system restore, os I am not familiar with it.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with it myself but I will figure something out, well either way I'm going out of the question. Too bad the answer to my question is a No, but it is a answer and the one I firstly assumed. Anyway, thanks Mike.